# <tr> border adds an additional 1px

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I need to implement row selection in a table, but when I set `border: 1px;` to entire row, it is set inside the table on the left side, but on the right side it's `1px` outside.

[image]

Does anyone now how to make it inside the table too?

Thanks!

```css
table {
  margin: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  background: lime;
}

tr:first-child + tr {
    border:1px solid red;
}

td {
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>item1</td><td>item2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>item3</td><td>item4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>item5</td><td>item6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please read the tag description before using them

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-shadow` with `inset`

```css
table {
  margin: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  background: lime;
}

tr:first-child + tr {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red inset;
}

td {
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>item1</td><td>item2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>item3</td><td>item4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>item5</td><td>item6</td></tr>
</table>
```